# example.com/dir/index.php works but example.com/dir/ doesn't

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm on Linux CENT OS 6.3 with latest php and latest apache,

on httpd.conf I got

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I go to:

```
example.com/mydir/index.php
```

it works, but it does not work for example.com/mydir/

it is a problem to me.

Actually might it have to do with something in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/pics/([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]*.*)?$ users/$1/pics/$2
#levanta de users/pics

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/vids/([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]*.*)?$ users/$1/vids/$2
#levanta de users/vids

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.(html|png|jpg|gif|jpeg|css|js)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/(.*))?$ - [L]


RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !settingsd
RewriteRule ^settings settingsd/settings.php

RewriteRule ^lists/ master/index.php
RewriteRule ^lists/(.*)$ $1


RewriteRule ^index\.(php) master/index.php
#levanta de master/


RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|php)|pokes|settings|subgram
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)?$ master/$2

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !pokesd
RewriteRule ^pokes(.*)$ pokesd/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !pokes|subgram
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+.php)?$    master/$2
#levanta de master/


RewriteRule   ^messages/ messages.php

RewriteRule    ^notes/me/ notes/notes.php 
RewriteRule    ^notes/drafts/ notes/notes_drafts.php
RewriteRule    ^notes/tagged/ notes/notes_tagged.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !photos_albums|photos_stream
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/photos $1/view_photos.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/photos_albums $1/view_photos.php?sk=photos_albums
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/photos_stream $1/view_photos.php?sk=photos_stream

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/friends $1/view_friends.php


RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !listsd
RewriteRule ^bookmarks/lists(.*)$ bookmarks/listsd/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^v(.*)$ v/video_embed.php?sbid=$1

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|php)|notes/me/|notes/drafts/|notes/tagged/
RewriteRule    ^notes/ notes/



RewriteRule ^r.php$ gvrrgvrr45.php$1
```

It has to do with a rule in there because when I strip it all and upload to the server clean it suddenly works, that same .htaccess was working in Windows but isn't working in this config.

Comment: If you add an index.html to the directory does the /mydir/ work then? Not sure about Linux but in Windows you have to set the default document.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work with index.html

Comment: yeah it's definitely that htaccess file I'll be fixing it, it works well on another server configuration though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to .htaccess . It's your Apache setting ( `/etc/httpd.conf` )

Check your [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) directive settings. It should have at least `index.php` to support your needs :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtm index.shtml index.php
```

or remove any entries that does not fit your need.

Comment: But if I strip the .htaccess content and upload it works . it is `DirectoryIndex index.php` in httpd.conf

Comment: the highest chance of having issue is on `master/index.php` lines, but you are not in that directory.